# scikit-learn fit function returns immediately with 0 training samples processed

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am experiencing an issue with `scikit-learn` version `1.3.2`, where the `fit()` function of the `MLPClassifier` returns almost instantly without processing any training samples. This is evident as the model's `t_` parameter (indicating the number of training samples seen by the solver during fitting) remains at `0`.

This problem occurred while attempting to fit a dataset with over 100,000 training samples, where the `fit()` function returned in less than 10 milliseconds. The following minimal example replicates the issue:

```py
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

X = [[1., 2.], [3., 4.]]
y = [1, 0]

clf = MLPClassifier(solver="lbfgs", alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2))
clf.fit(X, y)

print(clf.t_)  # Outputs: 0
```

I have searched but haven't found similar issues reported. Any insights into why this might be happening would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I observed this behavior consistently across multiple `scikit-learn` models.

Comment: It does predict correctly though, so it has 'learned' (try `clf.predict([[3,4],[1,2]])` for example).

Comment: My result is array([1, 1]) for that, it has not learned at all. @Marijn

Similarly if the input data is set like this: X = np.random.rand(10_000, 10),
y = np.random.randint(2, size=10_000)

It will still return in <10ms.